# Error in sort.list(y) whlie using 'Strata()' in R

Tags: r

When I run the command:

```
H <-length(table(data$Team))

n.h <- rep(5,H)

strata(data, stratanames=data$Team,size=n.h,method="srswor"),
```

I get the error statement:

```
'Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list' Have you called 'sort' on a list?'
```

Please help me how can I get this stratified sample. The variable 'Team' is 'Factor' type.

Data is as below:

```
zz <- "Team League.ID   Player  Salary  POS G   GS  InnOuts PO  A
ANA AL  molinjo0    335000  C   73  57  1573    441 37
ANA AL  percitr0    7833333 P   3   0   149 1   3
ARI NL  bautida0    4000000 RF  141 135 3536    265 8
ARI NL  estalbo0    550000  C   7   3   92  19  2
ARI NL  finlest0    7000000 CF  104 102 2689    214 5
ARI NL  koplomi0    330000  P   72  0   260 6   23
ARI NL  sparkst0    500000  P   27  18  362 8   21
ARI NL  villaos0    325000  P   17  0   54  0   4
ARI NL  webbbr01    335000  P   33  35  624 13  41
ATL NL  francju0    750000  1B  125 71  1894    627 48
ATL NL  hamptmi0    14625000    P   35  29  517 13  37
ATL NL  marreel0    3000000 LF  90  42  1125    80  4
ATL NL  ortizru0    6200000 P   32  34  614 7   38
BAL AL  surhobj0    800000  LF  100 31  805 69  0"

data <- read.table(text=zz, header=T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really answer your question, but a *long* time ago, I wrote a function called `stratified` that might be of use to you.

I've posted it [here as a GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6424112).

Notice that when you have asked for samples that are bigger than your data, it just returns all of the relevant rows.

```
output <- stratified(data, "Team", 5)
# Some groups
# ---ANA, ATL, BAL---
#   contain fewer observations than desired number of samples.
# All observations have been returned from those groups.
table(output$Team)
# 
# ANA ARI ATL BAL 
#   2   5   4   1 
output
#    Team League.ID   Player   Salary POS   G  GS InnOuts  PO  A
# 1   ANA        AL molinjo0   335000   C  73  57    1573 441 37
# 2   ANA        AL percitr0  7833333   P   3   0     149   1  3
# 9   ARI        NL webbbr01   335000   P  33  35     624  13 41
# 7   ARI        NL sparkst0   500000   P  27  18     362   8 21
# 8   ARI        NL villaos0   325000   P  17   0      54   0  4
# 3   ARI        NL bautida0  4000000  RF 141 135    3536 265  8
# 6   ARI        NL koplomi0   330000   P  72   0     260   6 23
# 12  ATL        NL marreel0  3000000  LF  90  42    1125  80  4
# 13  ATL        NL ortizru0  6200000   P  32  34     614   7 38
# 10  ATL        NL francju0   750000  1B 125  71    1894 627 48
# 11  ATL        NL hamptmi0 14625000   P  35  29     517  13 37
# 14  BAL        AL surhobj0   800000  LF 100  31     805  69  0
```

---

I'll add official documentation to the function at some point, but here's a summary to help you get the best use out of it:

The arguments to `stratified` are:

- `df`: The input `data.frame`
- `group`: A character vector of the column or columns that make up the "strata".
- `size`: The desired sample size.

  - If `size` is a value less than 1, a proportionate sample is taken from each stratum.
  - If `size` is a single integer of 1 or more, that number of samples is taken from each stratum.
  - If `size` is a vector of integers, the specified number of samples is taken for each stratum. It is recommended that you use a *named vector*. For example, if you have two strata, "A" and "B", and you wanted 5 samples from "A" and 10 from "B", you would enter `size = c(A = 5, B = 10)`.
- `select`: This allows you to subset the groups in the sampling process. This is a `list`. For instance, if your `group` variable was "Group", and it contained three strata, "A", "B", and "C", but you only wanted to sample from "A" and "C", you can use `select = list(Group = c("A", "C"))`.
- `replace`: For sampling with replacement.

Comment: Thank you very much Ananada. This function really works perfectly.

Comment: @user2742844, Glad to hear it. I've added a description of the arguments to the function so you can hopefully get more mileage out of it :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
library(sampling)

H <- length(levels(data$Team))
n.h <- rep(5, H)
strata(data, stratanames=c("Team"), size=n.h, method="srswor")
```

`stratanames` should be a list of column names, not a reference to the actual column data.

---

**Update:** 
Now that example data is available, I see another problem: you are sampling without-replacement (wor), but your samples are bigger that the available data. You need to sample with replacement in this case

```
  smpl <- strata(data, stratanames=c("Team"), size=n.h, method="srswr")
```

BTW, you get the actual data with:

```
 sampledData <- getdata(data, smpl)
```

Comment: I have not understood what does the code line:'data = data.frame(x=rnorm(100), 
      Team=sample(c("Blue","Red", "Yellow", "Blue"), 100, replace=T)' means and how to use it in my program. I already have a data with 35 variables and I need to take a stratified random sample from this data. Need to use 'Team' as strata.

Comment: @user2742844: that is example data. Since you did not provide an example which included any data to test the problem/solution, I added this so people can try out the code. It is generally a good practice to create self-contained examples (especially in questions).

Comment: Thank u so much for yur support, but this is not working. I am getting the same error.

Comment: Actually I just observed that when I load the library(sampling) following errors occur: 
> library(sampling)
Loading required package: lpSolve
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  could not find function ".getNamespace"
In addition: Warning message:
package 'sampling' was built under R version 3.0.1 
Error : unable to load R code in package 'sampling'
Error: package/namespace load failed for 'sampling'